# Send message to content script after page load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to iterate over an array of URL's inside `background.js`. For each URL, I want it to navigate the current tab, and then send a message to the `content_script.js` telling it to perform an action.

The problem is it's sending it immediately and not when the page loads (in fact it sends it before even updating the URL)

**background.js:**

```
  chrome.tabs.update(null, {
    url: 'https://www.example.com/' + path
  }, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {message: 'update_user'});
  });
```

**content_script.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.message === 'update_user') {
      console.log('loaded');
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: The problem is likely that navigating to a new URL is async. for example if you run `window.location.href = ...; console.log("hello");`, hello will be printed and then the page will change. You can check that this is whats happening by logging `tab.status` before sending the message. It will either be "loading" or "complete". Are you getting "loading"?

Comment: I can't check at the moment but I'm certain the answer would be yes.. I can tell by not even trying it because if I do a console.log('anything') before it, I can see the prints it for a split second *before* the window redirects. Then, after the redirect that clears the console, so the word disappears, proving it logs before it even redirects.

Comment: you can check "preserve log" in devtools so that the redirect doesn't clear it. It will even log a line when the navigation takes place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if the async page load is your issue, something like this could help:

```
chrome.tabs.update(null, {
        url: url
    }, function (tab) {
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function listener (tabId, info) {
            if (info.status === 'complete' && tabId === tab.id) {
                chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(listener);
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {message: 'update_user'});
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This adds a separate listener to `onUpdated` for each of the bad URLs. Each listener is only good for the single tab that was explicitly opened so there is no chance of "accidents".

Once the tab is loaded the listener is removed and the message is sent.

Comment: Interesting... with this method is there the possibility of the content script "accidentally firing"? I ask this because the action I'm performing is a very dangerous action (it's banning a user), and because it triggers immediately on every page load, I want to make sure that if I visit a GOOD profile it doesn't automatically start running code to ban someone. The only time it can execute is if I explicitly loop over it in background

Comment: The current way I'm handing this is very ghetto (because I couldn't get the message passing method to work). I simply redirect to a URL with a `?key={{uuid}}` query string, and then in the content script I make sure the query string variable matches before doing the dangerous action. Id prefer however that it's explicit via a message pass so theres no accidentally adding the query string and banning a user you didnt mean to

Comment: hm. I see what you mean. when in this flow do you know whether the profile is "good" or not? I imagine you have some parsing logic to determine whether a ban is necessary. where does it go?

Comment: Basically the initial loop determines that (it comes from an input box in the extension popup window, and that gets sent to the background via a message). That array of URL's that the user pastes in is what I loop over. I didnt include the loop code in my example, I just simplified it to a single `chrome.tabs.update` call, but you can imagine it simply as calling that for every URL, delaying 4 seconds in between (using some ES6 await timeouts) (loop -> ban -> wait 4 seconds -> loop...)

Comment: Okay and where do you check whether the page is good or bad? In the `content_script`?

Comment: Well currently I check in the content script (using the ?key={{uuid}} method). However, the only reason I used that method is because I couldnt get message passing to work (my current solution doesnt send any messages at all, it just redirects it and checks for the ?key=). I want to switch to message passing though so I don't have to rely on a query string. I can simply redirect & message pass immediately (explicitly) so that theres no accidental triggering. So the 'check' would essentially be the array itself, because that will never be incorrect urls. then i would just delete the whole ?key

Comment: so you already know ahead of time which URLs are bad? and paste those into the extension dialog?

Comment: Correct, all URLs will be bad that the user pastes in. But I just want to prevent manually typing in a URL (say.. a few hours later when not using the extension) and the code triggers on that page of the same website which is a good profile

Comment: I'll mark it as correct even though I havent tested yet, and Ill let you know how it goes when I get home